# lxml 3.6.4 installation error for python 3.5 on win 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, lxml, libxml2

When I try to install **lxml** for python 3.5 on Windows 10 by using `pip install lxml` I get the error message as follows:

```
"b" 'xslt-config' is nor recognized as an external or internal command, 
\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n" ** make sure the developement 
packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
```

The problem is I cannot figure out how to install libxml2 since the setup files for libxml2 return `"failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir"`

Any suggestions on how I fix these issues?

Comment: some libraries may need C/C++ `*.h` files with headers - to compile code. So probably you need source code or at least `libxml2-dev` with `*.h` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile lxml from sources without having the dependent libs avaiable to link against, and a working toolchain (which requires a matching version of Visual Studio on windows for your python version)

download a pre-compiled binary wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

Install it with pip:

```
pip install path-to-lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```